Doing or being?
How to reconcile following two quotes:

We are so obsessed with doing that we have no time and no imagination
left for being. As a result, men are valued not for what they are but
for what they do or what they have—for their usefulness. ~Thomas
Merton

and

The purpose of life is not to be happy at all. It is to be useful, to
be honorable. It is to be compassionate. It is to matter, to have it
make some difference that you lived.
~ Leo Rosten


Compassion can be non-doing, e.g. Kandaraka Sutta described here  ("At this point, no mention is made of outgoing action:) "By getting rid of the taint of ill-will, he lives benevolent in mind; and compassionate for the welfare of all creatures and beings, ...""

There is no contradiction: "to be useful, to be honorable, to be compassionate" are not conditions but actions.

That reminds me of an old bathroom-stall joke:
“To be is to do.” — Socrates
“To do is to be.” — Sartre
“Do be do be do.” — Sinatra

At any rate, the way to reconcile these two quotes is to realize that Merton is talking about (what I imagine he would call) 'vain' work. Money-grubbing, status-seeking, thoughtless striving after meaningless accomplishments, etc… Win or lose, those kinds of labor are a soul-suck, reducing one to the status of Gollum: a twisted creature whose entire self-worth lies in having and holding some powerful but ultimately empty token. On the other hand, Rosten is talking about 'engaged' work: work that we pour part of ourselves into because it will ultimately make the world a bit better of a place and last beyond us when we're gone. That kind of work is fulfilling.
In the end, 'being' and 'doing' are intimately intertwined, the question being whether we allow what we do to corrupt who we are, or allow who we are to inform what we do.

Excellent answer to the OP. A comment: words have several meanings, always, which makes some disantangling useful. "Being" can be understood essentially i.e. referring to something or someone's essence often seen as Platonic and inalterable -- or it can be understood existentially or phenomenologically, as our day-to-day experience of being-at-the-world. In the latter sense, it is indeed close to an activity.

"Do be a do-bee." -- Romper Room. (Typo fixed.)
